# Google Search console, Duplicate without user-selected canonical

Tags: search, console, canonical-link

I have a website that only has 3 pages. The google somehow still doesn't recognize the canonical pages and sends the Duplicate, Google chose different canonical than user -error when using the canonical tag.

How is it possible for google to not recognize the correct pages after they have been up for a year?

Any help would be appreciated!